# Prevent Overlap in Dynamically Created Divs in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, collision-detection, overlap, limits

I am currently working on a webpage where an array of draggable images appear in random positions over time. I would like to prevent the newly created divs from overlapping as well as create a limit to how many new divs appear.

Below is the current code That I have;

```
var Images = ['https://material.io/icons/static/images/icons-180x180.png', 'https://iconscout.com/ms-icon-310x310.png', 'https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Food//cherry1600.png', 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Ax2wQYxjDITuZEpc6K9EDYPG7C839tb4PApia4Tmf18u8XehB-twqhVgDVPgxxExkr4=w300', 
  'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ninja-things-1/1772/ninja-simple-256.png',
'http://files.softicons.com/download/game-icons/super-mario-icons-by-sandro-pereira/ico/Mushroom%20-%201UP.ico'],
        screenWidth, 
        screenHeight;

$(document).ready(function() {
    screenWidth = $(window).width();
    screenHeight = $(window).height();

    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        screenWidth = $(window).width();
      screenHeight = $(window).height();
    })

    setInterval(function () {
        var x = Math.random() * screenWidth,
                y = Math.random() * screenHeight;
        addDiv(x, y);
    }, 2000);
});

function addDiv(x,y) {
    var randImageIndex = Math.floor( (Math.random() * (Images.length - 1) ) );
    var Image = Images[randImageIndex];
    var newDiv = $('<div class="object"><img src=' + Image + ' height="100" width="100"></div>').css({top:x,left:y});

    $('body').append(newDiv); 

        newDiv.draggable();
    newDiv.on('click', function() { 
        $(this).remove(); 
    })
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!